# Primeng Turbo Table autoLayout not working on simple p-table

Tags: angular, primeng

I have this simple primeng 7.0 turbo table , p-table. It is non resizeable and non scrollable. Nothing I do seems to be affecting this table's layout. The autoLayout should work as it is first of all as per the documentation. Can someone comment what could be wrong with this ?

```
<p-table #availableTable [value]="sourceCars" selectionMode="multiple" 
[(selection)]="selectedItemsSource" [autoLayout]="true">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
            </tr>            
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="car">
                <td>{{car.label}}</td>
                <td>{{car.value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

My component file :

```
`
     import {Component, OnInit}      from '@angular/core';
     import {MenuItem} from "primeng/primeng";
     import {DialogService} from 'primeng/api';
    import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';

    @Component({
        selector: 'ivp-data-view',
        templateUrl: './data-view.html',
        styleUrls: ['./data-view.css'],
        providers: [DatamartService,DialogService]
    })
    export class DataViewComponent implements OnInit {
        items: MenuItem[];
        profileName: string
        display : boolean;
        cars: SelectItem[]
        sourceCars: SelectItem[];

        constructor( private dmService: DatamartService,public dialogService: 
    DialogService ) {

            this.sourceCars = [
                {label: 'Audi', value: 'Audi'},
                {label: 'BMW', value: 'BMW'},
                {label: 'Fiat', value: 'Fiat'},
                {label: 'Ford', value: 'Ford'},
                {label: 'Honda', value: 'Honda'},
                {label: 'Jaguar', value: 'Jaguar'},
                {label: 'Mercedes', value: 'Mercedes'},
                {label: 'Renault', value: 'Renault'},
                {label: 'VW', value: 'VW'},
                {label: 'Volvo', value: 'Volvo'}
            ];
        }

        public ngOnInit() {


            this.items = [{
                label: 'Explorer',
                items: [
                    {label: 'Details', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus'}
                ]
           }];
        }

    `




}
```

[My table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH3Ut.png)

[My table with same code ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFDO6.png)

Comment: Can you share the component file too?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding , Here it is.

Comment: I have added it to the original post. To reduce the length took out some of the code which was not related.

Comment: It makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the primeNG [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) says about the property `autoLayout`:

`Whether the cell widths scale according to their content or not.`

It means the column should resize to avoid overflow when the content is too big.

I did some tests the property `scrollable` and `scollHeight`, and I got the scroll behavior that you must need.

I put the code in the stackblitz to ease tests:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arzgvr

Comment: This is strange. My above code to set autolayout true on table also was same as yours , but I see the auto layout working for you but not for me. I am trying again.

Comment: Probably the auto layout is working for me too . Attached a pic in link "My table with same code" . Its just not obvious since even after applying the auto layout the column width is still way too big for the data. The data is very short strings.